# TV episode or possibly movie involving teenagers at a costume party having their brains sucked out by an evil alien force

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, tv

I need help finding a TV episode or possibly science fiction movie that I remember from the 90s.

It takes place primarily at a teenage Halloween/costume party. These partygoers find this secret room inside the house and when they enter, they are immediately lined up against the wall and have their brains sucked out by an evil alien force, I think. In the end they are all rescued by some other partygoers.

I don't believe anyone died, but I think in the end the alien returned to space or something.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was there any visible gore and do you recall if anyone actually died?

Comment: I don't believe anyone died, but I think in the end the alien returned to space or something. Thanks.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Was there possibly a "War of the Worlds" aspect to the story, where the party was a costume party?

Comment: Yes Emsley, I believe that may have been the theme. I wish I could provide more details, but I saw this show or movie in the early 90s when I was only about 10 years old. That's all I can remember. Thanks to everyone who is trying to help out, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Possibly *Buffy*, Season 4 Episode 4: “Fear Itself”: https://www.denofgeek.com/tv/buffy-the-vampire-slayer-revisiting-4-classic-halloween-episodes/